# php regex to match key value pairs

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like as below.

```
$string = "height=175cm weight=70kgs age=25yrs"
```

String contents are key value pairs each pair are separated by a Tab. I want each key value pairs as separate variable and prints out each.
I have tried with below code but i am not getting proper result please help me where i went wrong.

```
$string = "height=175cm weight=70kgs age=25yrs";
$pattern = "(([^=]*)\s*=\s*(.*))";
if (preg_match($pattern,$string,$match)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($match);
} else {
    echo "not matche\n";
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => height=175cm weight=70kgs age=25yrs
    [1] => height
    [2] => 175cm weight=70kgs age=25yrs
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
$string = "height=175cm weight=70kgs    age=25yrs";
if (preg_match_all('/\s*([^=]+)=(\S+)\s*/', $string, $matches)) {
   $output = array_combine ( $matches[1], $matches[2] );
   print_r($output);   
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [height] => 175cm
    [weight] => 70kgs
    [age] => 25yrs
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$string = "height=175cm weight=70kgs age=25yrs";
$pattern = "/(\w+)=(\d+)(\w+)/i";

if(preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$match))
{
     var_dump($match);
}
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "height=175cm"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "weight=70kgs"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "age=25yrs"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "height"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "weight"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "age"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "175"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "70"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "cm"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "kgs"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "yrs"
  }
}
```

Comment: The `i` pattern modifier doesn't benefit this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I've pasted a code sample below which helps you to solve your problem.  Certainly, it is not very tightly compressed and has quite a few more lines of code than the other answers (which are all good answers!).

The reason I did this was because it looks like you may benefit from an explanation that takes you one step at a time in the progression of solving your problem, so that you can understand what is happening along the way.

Here's the code you can use:

```
<?php

$string = "height=175cm\tweight=70kgs\tage=25yrs";

// Divide your string into an array, with each element
// in the array being a string with a key-value pair
$pairs = explode("\t", $string);

// See what the array of pair strings looks like.
// print_r($pairs); 

// Create an array to get it ready to hold key-value pairs.
$results = array();

// For each string in your array, split at the equal sign
// and set values in the $results array.
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
  $exploded_pair = explode("=", $pair);

  // See what each exploded pair array looks like.
  // print_r($exploded_pair);

  $key = $exploded_pair[0];
  $value = $exploded_pair[1];
  $results[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($results);
```

Instead of using regular expressions, this makes use of the `explode` function in PHP.  You can read the documentation on `explode` [found here](http://php.net/explode).

You said that your input string is separated by tabs, which is why the assignment statement for `$string` has `\t` instead of spaces.  If you were to use spaces instead of tabs, then make sure that  you change

```
$pairs = explode("\t", $string);
```

to

```
$pairs = explode(" ", $string);
```